# When does a GitHub workflow trigger for merge_group and is it restricted by branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to achieve a setup like this using GitHub Actions:

1. Pull Requests must be reviewed, build and pass unit tests
2. Once those conditions are met, they can be added to the merge queue
3. Once in the merge queue, GitHub will attempt to deploy the merge group
4. If the deployment succeeds, then the code is merged
5. If deployment fails, the offending PR is removed from the merge group and we try again with the new merge group

I have a deployment workflow with this trigger in GitHub Actions:

```yaml
on:
  merge_group:
```

I only want this to run for merge groups that are targeting `master`.

Is this trigger correct?

Is there a way to specify which branches it is triggered for?

Answer (score 5):

Note the following prerequisites to use Merge Queue:

1. Must have a public repository owned by an organization, or a private repository owned by an organization using GitHub Enterprise Cloud.
2. Merge Queue configuration requires Admin Access to repository settings.

I've found that if you only include the `merge_group` trigger, the workflow will fail to run. Instead, you should add both `pull_request` and `merge_group` triggers, as well as filter for the `github merge_group` event for each job like so:

(based on https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/51120#discussioncomment-6312578)

```
on:
  pull_request:
  merge_group:

jobs:
  deployment:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'merge_group' }}
```

Then, in the GitHub repository Settings -> Branch Protection Rules, create a rule for the branch you want to apply the queue to (most likely `main`, I believe currently only having 1 queue is supported).

Check the box for "**Require status checks to pass before merging**" and add the names of the **jobs** you want to run from your workflow under required status checks (in this example, it would be `deployment`).

Check the box for "**Require merge queue**" and configure options according to what suits your repository.

Scroll to the bottom and **Save changes**.

This workaround is a little bit ugly as it will have skipped workflows on open PRs that technically pass, but as far as I can tell, this is the only way to ensure the workflow you want runs in merge queue without running per PR commit/push. Hopefully they will change the trigger behavior in the future.

Comment: In fact, the workflow with just the `merge_queue` event will totally run, but you need two important conditions to be met: 
1. The job should have the same name as the PR check workflow
2. The job with that name should be a required check.

Please see this article for an example that I've confirmed works: https://medium.com/@kojoru/how-to-set-up-merge-queues-in-github-actions-59381e5f435a

Answer (score 2):

To add to kevya-google's otherwise [thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76740962/319229), it must be noted that **there is a way to coerce GitHub into running separate workflows in pull requests and in merge queues**. The prerequisites are as follows:

1. You need to have both a `pull_request` and a `merge_group` workflow.
2. The main job in both workflows needs to have the same name.

So, you create two workflows along these lines:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  validate-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: pull request
      run: echo "this runs in PR branch"
```

```yaml
on:
  merge_group:

jobs:
  validate-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: queue
      run: echo "this runs in merge queue"
```

Note how both files have the main job called `validate-pr`.

Then you add the job `validate-pr` as a required check in your branch protection settings, and voilá - you have a workflow that only has a `merge_group` event running as expected.

I have set up a [test repository](https://github.com/kojoru-sandbox/MergeQueues) that you can fork and see it working for yourself (don't forget to enable Actions that are disabled by default in forks)

### Background

The reason that `merge_groups` don't trigger the workflow without this set up has to do with its roots in the GitHub Automerge functionality.

Without merge queues, when you set the branch to automerge, it will merge as soon as all required checks pass. So, for example, if you have three workflows, but only one of them is required in the branch protection rules, GitHub will not wait for the two non-required workflows to pass.

Merge queue is the same thing. It will merge the queue as soon as all the required checks are passed, so if your `merge_group` request is not required, it will not even have a chance to be run.

Unfortunately, there's no way to separately set different required checks between pull requests and merge queues, so you also need a separate trick with the matching name. This way GitHub thinks of them as the same check, even if they are completely different workflow files otherwise.